# Is it possible to add multiple variables to templates and configurations?

Tags: m2doc

I'm using M2Doc on an EMF model and are able to generate a document with some model contents. The scope of the access to the model is at the moment limited to the single variable configured for the template and subsequently the configuration file. So I can only access a single file in the workspace project folder.

As my model contains information spread across multiple files: Is it possible to configure multiple variables, each connected to a different project file? All the configuration dialogs are actually lists, but there's no button to add additional line items.

Did I miss any setting? Is this planned for the future?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can add calls to new variables in your template:

```
{ m:myVar2.name }
```

Then, after saving your template, use the [Template properties wizard](https://www.m2doc.org/ref-doc/nightly/#template-properties-wizard) to define the type of the new variable. It can be an EClass from your metamodel or a primitive type (String, Integer, ...). Then you will need to bind its value in your .genconf file.

For the moment the genconf wizard doesn't allow binding of Sequence nor OrderedSet. There is an [issue](https://github.com/ObeoNetwork/M2Doc/issues/419) opened for that matter.

Comment: Ah, great, so first one is directly created, others via the Word template.
My individual model files currently do not provide all types, which limits the type selection of additional variables. I guess I would need to create a (dummy) model file with all known types, so that I have full choice for additional variables, right?
Or do you see an even simpler way?

Comment: You need to add the nsURI of your metamodel (EPackage) to your template in order to be able to select a type (an EClass) from this metamodel. see the template properties wizard in the documentation.